# Image<Bgr, byte> image copy in thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, emgucv

Im trying use image.copy() inside of method called for one thread, like the example bellow:

```
 public static unsafe void recognise(Image<Bgr, byte> imgOriginal)
    {    (...)
            Rectangle piece_square = new Rectangle(...);           
            Image<Bgr, byte> square_image = imgOriginal.Copy(piece_square);

        }
    }
```

These method is called like that:

```
Thread aux = new Thread(() => recognise(imgOriginal))
 aux.Start();
```

And it throws these exception "Emgu.CV.Util.CvException".

What can be causing that?

Comment: Any chance that you could provide a [mcve]? It'll certainly improve your chances of getting a good answer.